# Zip code distance R

Tags: r, geospatial, distance, zipcode

I'm using the Zip Code package in R, and I'd like to make a list of all zip codes that are within a 10, 20, or X mile radius from each zip code. From there I will roll up zip code data to a 10, 20, or X mile total. I'm currently joining every single zip code, with each zip code (so the number of rows squares). Then calculating the distance between each zip code. And then eliminating the distances where greater than 10,20, X miles. Is there a better way to do this in R so I do not have to calculate all possibilities? I'm brand new to R. Thanks!

```
Code is here:
#Bringing in Zipcode database. 
library(zipcode)
data(zipcode)

#Limiting to certain states that I want to include,
SEZips <- zipcode[zipcode$state %in% c("GA","AL", "SC", "NC"),]

#Duplicating the data set to join it together
SEZips2 <- SEZips

#To code in SQL
library(sqldf)

#Creating a common match so I can join all rows from both tables together
SEZips$Match <- 1
SEZips2$Match <- 1

#attaches every zip code to each zip
ZipList <- sqldf("
                 SELECT
                 A.zip as zip1,
                 A.longitude as lon1,
                 A.latitude as lat1,
                 B.zip as zip2,
                 B.longitude as lon2,
                 B.latitude as lat2
                 From SEZips A
                 Left Join SEZips2 B
                 on A.Match = B.Match
                 ")


#to get the distance calculation, use package geosphere, 
library(geosphere)

#radius of Earth in miles, adjust for km, etc.
r = 3959
#Creating Table of the coordinates. Makes it easy to calc distance
Points1 <- cbind(ZipList$lon1,ZipList$lat1)
Points2 <- cbind(ZipList$lon2,ZipList$lat2)
distance <- distHaversine(Points1,Points2,r)

#Adding distance back on to the original ZipList
ZipList$Distance <- distance

#To limit to a certain radius.E.g. 15 for 15 miles.
z = 15
#Eliminating matches > z 
ZipList2 <- ZipList[ZipList$Distance <= z,]

#Adding data to roll up, e.g. population
ZipPayroll <- read.csv("filepath/ZipPayroll.csv")

#Changin Zip to 5 character from integer. A little bit of pain
#Essentailly code says (add 5 0's, and then grab the right 5 characters)
ZipPayroll$Zip2 <- substr(paste("00000",ZipPayroll$zip,sep=""),nchar(paste("00000",ZipPayroll$zip,sep=""))-4,nchar(paste("00000",ZipPayroll$zip,sep="")))

#Joining Payroll info to SEZips dataframe
SEZips <- sqldf("
                SELECT
                A.*,
                B.Payroll, 
                B.Employees,
                B.Establishments
                From SEZips A
                Left Join ZipPayroll B
                on A.zip = B.Zip2
                ")

#Rolling up to 15 mile level
SEZips15 <- sqldf("
                  SELECT
                  A.zip1 as Zip, 
                  Sum(B.Payroll) as PayrollArea,
                  Sum(B.Employees) as EmployeesArea,
                  Sum(B.Establishments) as EstablishmentsArea
                  From ZipList2 A
                  Left Join SEZips B
                  on A.zip2 = B.zip
                  Group By A.zip1
                  ")

#Include the oringinal Zip data 
SEZips15 <- sqldf("
                  SELECT
                  A.*,
                  B.Payroll,
                  B.Employees,
                  B.Establishments as EstablishmentsArea
                  From SEZips15 A
                  Left Join SEZips B
                  on A.zip = B.zip
                  ")

#Calculate Average Pay for Zip and Area
SEZips15$AvgPayArea <- SEZips15$PayrollArea / SEZips15$EmployeesArea
SEZips15$AvgPay <- SEZips15$Payroll / SEZips15$Employees
```

Comment: Your current code compares every zip code to every other zip code twice actually. (16127 as A, 27513 as B... then 27513 as A, 16127 as B.) You can cut the work in half by only comparing once. If you think of it as a 2-dimensional grid or table, you only need to do the matches above a diagonal from top left to bottom right. Also, you can just do your join on `1 = 1` and avoid creating the `match` variables...

Comment: Also, as a follow-up question... Are you running into performance issues? If not, your solution is probably fine... If so, you can benefit from optimizing...

Comment: Thanks John! In regards to comparing everything twice, I think I need both. For example I need Zip match 16127, 27513 and zip match 27513,16217,. This allows me to sum up all the zips around zip 16127 and 27513 separately. There will be overlap, which is expected.

Comment: I currently don't have optimization issues, but its only 4 states of data and it increases exponentially when i add more. I'm brand new to R, so I'm doing a lot in sqldf, and was curious if there was a more efficient method in r or some geospatial calc. Thanks for the tip on match btw!

Comment: The distance from zip 16127 to 27513 is the same as the distance from 27513 to 16127. If you want to save CPU cycles, you can calculate that distance once, and transform the data later if necessary. (Though transforming the data may be more computationally expensive than doing the calculation - try it out and see).

Answer (score 0):

I add below a solution using the spatialrisk package. The key functions in this package are written in C++ (Rcpp), and are therefore very fast.

The function spatialrisk::points_in_circle() calculates the observations within radius from a center point. Note that distances are calculated using the Haversine formula.

```
library(spatialrisk)
library(tidyverse)

zips_within_radius <- function(x,y,z) {
  points_in_circle(SEZips, x, y, lon = longitude, lat = latitude, radius = 10000) %>% 
    mutate(source_zip = z)
 }
```

Since each element of the output is a data frame, purrr::map_dfr is used to row-bind them together:

```
pmap_dfr(list(SEZips$longitude, SEZips$latitude, SEZips$zip), zips_within_radius)
```